# Add a dynamic dropdown to ribbon. OnAction Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, office365, ribbonx

I'm trying to add a dynamic dropdown to customised ribbon for an xlsm file.

The idea of the dropdown is to generate a list from an existing Excel range. A click on any item of the dropdown list should take the user to the same named worksheet.

I can generate the dropdown list but when I click it says

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

There are working customised ribbon buttons on that tab, so I think the problem may generate from the `xml` code part or the `onAction` subprocess part.

###### Xml

```
<!--            Dynamic dropDown Group                 -->          
                <group id="tool5" label="Sheet DropDown" autoScale="true">          
                    <dropDown id="DropDown1" label= "Sheet Name" sizeString="WWWWWWWWWWWWW" supertip="Please select a sheet, add more sheetsname in Lookup sheet" imageMso="InsertExcelSpreadsheetMenu"
                              getItemCount="GetDropdownItemCount" getItemLabel="DropdownItemLabel" onAction="SubdropDownAction" />    
                </group>
```

###### VBA

I think `GetDropdownItemCount` and `DropdownItemLabel` are working since the dropdown list is properly generated.

```vb
Public Sub SubdropDownAction(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer)
    
    Dim SelectedSheet As String

    Select Case control.ID
        
        Case "DropDown1"
            SelectedSheet = Range("Range_DropdownsheetName").Cells(index + 1).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SelectedSheet).Activate

        Case Else

    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to show GetDropdownItemCount and DropdownItemLabel
And which line produces the error - a breakpoint in SubdropDownAction and step through
And a guess is, that Range("Range_DropdownsheetName") is not declared with workbook and worksheet  this would only work, if the worksheet is active with the given range. Get all Values coming back in your SubdropDownAction

Answer (score 2):

The `dropDown` control must have the following signature for the `onAction` callback:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control, string selectedId, int selectedIndex)

VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, selectedId As String, selectedIndex As Integer)

C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in] BSTR *selectedId, [in] LONG cSelectedIndex)

Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, selectedId As String, selectedIndex As Integer)
```

So, your code should look like that:

```
Public Sub SubdropDownAction(control As IRibbonControl, selectedId As String, selectedIndex As Integer)
    
Dim SelectedSheet As String

    Select Case control.ID
        
        Case "DropDown1"
            SelectedSheet = Range("Range_DropdownsheetName").Cells(selectedIndex + 1).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SelectedSheet).Activate

        Case Else

    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Hope it helps, but you can set a breakpoint and see what is wrong with your code further.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't found the difference about controls with button or dropdown. Your answer perfectly solved the problem! Thank you again!